# Limit FTS to particular rows and column in my app

Tags: android, sqlite

I actually have a a couple of questions related to Search in my app.

This is my Search query right now:

```
SELECT Book_Name, PlainEng_Text, REF, Book_Number, Collection_ID
FROM Had_Table
WHERE Collection_ID = ...
  AND ID IN (SELECT ID
             FROM Had_Virtual_Table
             WHERE Had_Virtual_Table MATCH ?)
```

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Had_Virtual_Table USING FTS4(
  ID, PlainEng_Text, PlainArab_Text)
```

1. I would like to restrict inner query to a particular column(text search) and particular "Collection_ID" rows.
2. Is it possible to have search user-input words highlighted when I display the results in the app using `ListView` and `TextView`?

Comment: This is too broad; please ask only one question per question.

Comment: Show the table structure.

Comment: @CL. Here 

`CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Had_Virtual_Table " +
                        "USING FTS4(ID, PlainEng_Text, PlainArab_Text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FTS tables, all columns store strings. You should drop the `ID` colunm an instead use the [internal `rowid` colunm](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#populating_fts_tables).

To search only a column, use that column with MATCH:

```
... WHERE PlainEng_Text MATCH ?
```

In FTS tables, only full-text searches are efficient; try to restrict `Collection_ID` values would make it slower.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
I read that internal `rowid` is not reliable as your primary key. I forgot exactly what it was. It was something about Vacuum thing.

Comment: That would apply only to normal tables; FTS tables guarantee that the `rowid` is stable.

Comment: Will that always match to the `ID` column in the normal table ? I have `WHERE ID IN ` virtual_table ID.

Comment: You have to explicitly insert the desired value into that column.

Comment: Oh. That is I will just replace `ID` with `rowid` when inserting into virtual_table.

Ok. I will do that. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**For 1st Question**
Correct your Query: Give a space before `AND` on `Collection_ID = " + CID + " AND ID IN`

Use this Query

```
String sqlStr = "SELECT Book_Name, PlainEng_Text,  REF, Book_Number, Collection_ID FROM Had_Table WHERE Collection_ID = " + CID + " AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Had_Virtual_Table WHERE Had_Virtual_Table MATCH ?)";
```

**For Second Question**

This not a your expecting solution, But this will give a Idea to you

```
final TextView sampleText =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_sample_text);
EditText ed_texthere =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_texthere);

final String fullText = sampleText.getText().toString();

ed_texthere.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        String typedText = charSequence.toString();
        if (typedText != null && !typedText.isEmpty()) {
            int startPos = fullText.toLowerCase(Locale.US).indexOf(typedText.toLowerCase(Locale.US));
            int endPos = startPos + typedText.length();
            if (startPos != -1) {
                Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(fullText);
                ColorStateList blueColor = new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[]{}}, new int[]{Color.BLUE});
                TextAppearanceSpan highlightSpan = new TextAppearanceSpan(null, Typeface.BOLD, -1, blueColor, null);
                spannable.setSpan(highlightSpan, startPos, endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                sampleText.setText(spannable);
            } else {
                sampleText.setText(fullText);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
});
```

Comment: That query is same as mine? In my actual code I have `AND` etc with spaces. I just edited that for SO. 
The main thing about that query is I would like to restrict inner query search.

I will try to understand the code about Highlighting.

Thank you for your response.